# How can I get the different object between two two element datasets?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, command-behaviors

If I have these two files containing the following datasets:

OldFile:

```
"CanonicalName","LastSet"
"CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU1/Users/Active/Test User","2019-07-02 14:14:44"
"CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU1/Users/Active/User One","2019-07-02 14:14:44"
"CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU2/Users/Active/User Two","2018-09-02 05:53:35"
"CONTOSO.com/OC/AU/OU3/Users/User Three","2017-06-23 14:20:07"
```

TempFile:

```
"CanonicalName","LastSet"
"CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU1/Users/Active/User One","2019-07-02 14:14:44"
"CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU2/Users/Active/User Two","2018-09-02 05:53:35"
"CONTOSO.com/OC/AU/OU3/Users/User Three","2017-06-23 14:20:07"
```

That returns:

```
InputObject                                                                                  SideIndicator
-----------                                                                                  -------------
@{CanonicalName=CONTOSO.com/OC/AU/OU3/Users/User Three; LastSet=2017-06-23 14:20:07} <=
```

Where I would have expected it to return the TEST user with "<="  when the following code is executed:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (import-csv $oldfile) -DifferenceObject (import-csv $tempfile)
```

Why?  How can I get the desired output?  The DIFFERENT object.

Comment: aren't all objects different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Import-Csv` will return an array of `PSCustomObject` that has properties called `CanonicalName` and `LastSet`.

When `Compare-Object` has to compare complex objects with properties, you need to use the `-Property` parameter to tell it which properties to compare when testing for equality:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Import-Csv $oldfile) -DifferenceObject (Import-Csv $tempfile) -Property CanonicalName,LastSet
```

The result is then:

```
CanonicalName                                LastSet             SideIndicator
-------------                                -------             -------------
CONTOSO.com/NA/US/OU1/Users/Active/Test User 2019-07-02 14:14:44 <=
```

Comment: Ah!  I did not know that I could list more than one object in the property!  Will try this later tonight.